# Passport Token Laravel

Tags: laravel, tokens, passport

que tal buen día soy nuevo esto de los tokens y de laravel espero pueda darme una mano con mi problema, es el siguiente:

Tengo un select de ciudades que al onchange manda llamar datos en formato json para llenar otro select, el detalle es que el json viene sin protección y estuve leyendo sobre passport y lo implemente en mi proyecto de laravel.

**Pero el problema esta en que mi ruta es esta:**

```
Route::post( '/get-condado-list/', 'WelcomeController@getCondadoList' )->middleware('auth:api');
```

**Parte de mi ajax es este:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/get-condado-list/',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'id': _id, "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success: function (response) {


            }
        }
    });
```

**Pero la respuesta**

```
 {"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

Comment: El middleware para usar tu aplicación es api? De preferencia estas solicitudes son GET, y si necesitas usar este middleware, debes enviar un attributo `headers` en ajax donde incluyas Bearer + el token del usuario

Comment: Si estás consumiendo la api desde una vista en la misma aplicación, lo más fácil sería agregar el middleware `CreateFreshApiToken` al grupo de middleware web en el archivo `app/Http/Kernel.php` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: Fijate que el detalle es que esa url es publica es lo mas raro que me pidan que tokenice un json cuando esta dentro de un blade donde el usuario no necesita logearse, pero agradezco sus comentarios seguire sus alternativas, muchas gracias por compartir sus conocimientos.